# A countable set of irrational rotations

Tags: circles, isometry

Consider a circle $ \mathbb{T} $ and an irrational rotation $ f_{\theta} : \mathbb{T} \to \mathbb{T} \; x \mapsto  x+\theta $.

If we define $ f^0_\theta(x)=x $ and $ f^{n+1}_\theta = f^n_\theta \circ f_\theta$ we then can create a set $ F = \{ f^n_\theta : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ and the set $ F' = \{ f_\theta \circ x : x \in F \} $.

Does $ F = F' $ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Assuming your $\mathbb N$ includes $0$, $f^0_\theta$ is in $F$ but not in $F'$.

Comment: I realized that very soon after posting but was AFK.